# Solr indexing fails on server.request(up)

Tags: solr, indexing

while indexing into solr, i am getting an error like this.

```
 HTTP Status 500 - lazy loading error
 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: lazy loading error at
 org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWrappedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:260)
 at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:242)
 at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376) at
 org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
 at
 org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
 at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at
```

The URL formed is : `http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?Latitude=51.9125&Longitude=179.5&commit=true&waitFlush=true&waitSearcher=true&wt=javabin&version=2`

(I have configured tomcat using Xampp on Windows machine)

I have been following SOF and various other blogs/forums and tried to debug it but for hours i could not find anything.

I have added the following things in the solr.xml

```
<maxFieldLength>10000</maxFieldLength>
<writeLockTimeout>60000</writeLockTimeout>
<commitLockTimeout>60000</commitLockTimeout>

<lockType>simple</lockType>
<unlockOnStartup>true</unlockOnStartup>
<reopenReaders>true</reopenReaders>

<requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" 
multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000" />

<lst name="defaults">
<!--str name="echoParams">explicit</str-->
<!--int name="rows">10</int-->
<!--str name="df">text</str-->
<str name="Latitude">Latitude</str>
<str name="Longitude">Longitude</str>
</lst>
```

Even tried adding the following to solconfig.xml ands restarting tomcat i get

```
   <requestHandler name="/update/extract" class="org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler"> 
     <lst name="defaults"> 
     <str name="ext.map.Last-Modified">last_modified</str> 
     <bool name="ext.ignore.und.fl">true</bool> 
     </lst> 
     </requestHandler>
```

On the Java console it shows an error : 
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Internal Server Error

1. I realized the issue might be because of my solr home path. I created a new directory and copied all the config files there and mentioned that as my solr path. However, I later update the solrconfig.xml, correcting paths for all the jars.
2. Also tried adding the 'pdfbox and fontbox' jars in to solr lib folder and restarting Tomcat

My Java code is :

```
 String urlString = "http://localhost:8080/solr"; 
    SolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(urlString);
    ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
    String fileName=f.toString();
    up.addFile(new File(fileName));
    up.setParam("Latitude", Latitude);
    up.setParam("Longitude", Longitude);
    up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
    server.request(up);
```

(Port8080 is the one i have configured)

Still solr indexing is not working at my end.. i have tried hours debugging this and figuring out. It would be really great if you can show me some hint or suggest anything i am doing wrong.

> As for your ref i have already tried : 
>   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FrontPage
>   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ContentStreamUpdateRequestExample
>   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRichDocuments
>   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Configuration
>   http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Problem-using-ExtractingRequestHandler-with-tomcat-td494930.html
>   http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Internal-Server-Error-td715713.html
>   [How to index pdf's content with SolrJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693671/how-to-index-pdfs-content-with-solrj)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr Tomcat org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: lazy loading error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058991/solr-tomcat-org-apache-solr-common-solrexception-lazy-loading-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have solr-cell.jar in your class path.  ?

The ExtractingRequestHandler is in the solr-cell.jar, which is not packaged with the default solr-server

Comment: No i have not done it.. do you want me to add it to the java program path or to the path where i have installed solr ?

Comment: Also Thank you for answering.. good to see atleast a single answer after hours

Comment: Sorry I was out for while :) the solr-cell.jar needs to be in the solr-server webapp, under the web-inf lib.

Comment: Also, make sure that you have all the dependencies for solr-cell. If you are familiar with maven, here the the dependencies of [solr-cell 3.6] (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-cell/3.6.0)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I find a way to solve this.

Just modify `SOLR_HOME/conf/solrconfig.xml`, change all the dir attribute of `<tab>` tag from `"../../dist/"` to `"../dist/"`, save the file

If you encounter this problem, that the `solr` directory must be move from `apache-solr-x.x.x\example` to some other place, so the relative path `"../../dist/"` need to be changed accordingly.

Remember to restart your tomcat and see if it work.