# Solr Tomcat org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: lazy loading error

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, ubuntu-14.04

Ubuntu 14.04

I installed using sudo apt-get install solr-tomcat.

It seems the "core" functionality was installed and is working, but not any Plugins (or I just don't know where to look).

I am trying to use the [extract](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) function, which is a Plugin.

When I attempt, I get this

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: lazy loading error
>       at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWrappedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:260)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:242)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler'
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:414)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:419)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:455)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWrappedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:251)
>       ... 16 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:789)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:398)
>       ... 19 more

I manually downloaded the latest version just to investigate, and did find an "extraction" directory, and, within, a file called ExtractingRequestHandler.java.

I'm not a Java guy. I looked for a similar path to what the error indicated and found "/usr/share/maven-repo/org/apache/solr/solr-core", which does not strictly correspond with "org.apache.solr.core". So, I'm hesitant to assume anything here.

Solr is searching for the "extraction" directory - I'm just not sure where.

My solrconfig.xml file has this

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- All the main content goes into "text"... if you need to return
           the extracted text or do highlighting, use a stored field. -->
      <str name="fmap.content">text</str>
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>

      <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

I tried copying that extraction directory into both these directories:
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/apache/solr/
/etc/solr

in hopes that either was the 'home' solr directory, no luck.

I added

```
<lib dir="/var/lib/solr/contrib/extraction/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/extraction" />
```

to my solrconfig.xml and observed this in tomcat logs:

> INFO: Adding 'file:/var/lib/solr/contrib/extraction/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/extraction/ExtractingRequestHandler.java' to classloader

Still, no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I checked my tomcat logs and I see the following:

> Nov 23, 2014 12:53:44 AM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers
>   initHandlersFromConfig INFO: adding lazy requestHandler:
>   solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler

It's odd because it indicates that a "lazy requestHandler" was created at solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler, which contradicts the error:

> Error loading class 'solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler'

If I remove the "startup = 'lazy'" attribute from the config above, when I restart Tomcat, there is an error:

> SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class
>   'solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're adding a source directory to the classpath - you'll need to add the compiled version with its dependencies to the classpath instead.

In the normal distribution (from the Solr homepage) this is located in `contrib/extraction/lib`, where it also bundles the other dependencies for the extraction module.

From the README.txt in that directory:

> ### Getting Started
>
> You will need Solr up and running.  Then, simply add the extraction JAR file, plus the Tika dependencies (in the ./lib folder)
>   to your Solr Home lib directory.  See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler for more details on hooking it in
>    and configuring.

Although it seems you're following an older version of how to do this (from your request handler name). The [current configuration is detailed in the community wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika), and there's a complete example bundled in the distribution as well.

Retrieving and extracting the files:

```
$ wget http://<mirror>/lucene/solr/4.10.2/solr-4.10.2.tgz
$ tar xvzf solr-4.10.2.tgz
$ cd solr-4.10.2/contrib/extraction/lib/
$ ls
apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar    pdfbox-1.8.4.jar
apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar     poi-3.10.1.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar            poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar
bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar           poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar
bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar           poi-scratchpad-3.10.1.jar
boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar            rome-0.9.jar
commons-compress-1.7.jar        tagsoup-1.2.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                 tika-core-1.5.jar
fontbox-1.8.4.jar               tika-parsers-1.5.jar
icu4j-53.1.jar                  tika-xmp-1.5.jar
isoparser-1.0-RC-1.jar          vorbis-java-core-0.1.jar
jdom-1.0.jar                    vorbis-java-tika-0.1.jar
jempbox-1.8.4.jar               xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
jhighlight-1.0.jar              xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar     xmpcore-5.1.2.jar
metadata-extractor-2.6.2.jar    xz-1.4.jar
```

Comment: None of the [downloads](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/solr/4.10.2) have anything in that contrib/extraction/lib folder. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Downloading `solr-4.10.2.tgz` from one of the mirrors and extracting it gave 32 .jars in `solr-4.10.2/contrib/extraction/lib`. No idea what you're doing - I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: Whoa, I'm sorry for that. I was downloading the source and not the compiled version. It's working now, thanks a lot for your help.